# Can something be done about visibility of the "Item" reflected class?

Tags: android, renderscript

Is there a reason for using default visibility modifiers in the reflected "Item" class for RenderScript structures? Specifically, I would like to create these items in a package other than the one in which the root script is bound. For reasons of package management organization, I would like to be able to access some of the reflected data types from other packages so that I don't need to create an access class if at all possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to an answer I received by google in one of the Android Developer hangouts, due to the nature of how the RenderScript tool chain works, unless they decide to change it there is nothing that can be done by developers.